# Odroid xu4 ,ocam & arduino uno serial conection

Tags: c

I am a beginner who first encountered odroid.
I would like to send data values ​​through image processing to arduino uno using odroid xu4 and ocam. First, I wonder how to make serial communication between odroid and arduino for serial communication. How do I send data values ​​from odroid and ocam to arduino like above?

Comment: hi @kim_ks, the answer below was of any help? Sorry to resume it late.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. You need:
1)Serial communication Odroid-Arduino, and,
2)Send camera information.

For (2) you need to send complete image or maybe process it in Odroid and send features information or some image processing result to Arduino. To process image you can use something like OpenCV (https://opencv.org/).

For (1) you need to make physical (electrical) connection then logical communication.
For electrical connection, as Odroid operates at 1.8V you need level conversion to 5V or 3.3V(arduino) in connector pins (Odroid con10 for instance). You can look [here](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=4758&p) to know how to make it.

For logical part, you can use WiringPi ported to Odroid, refer [here](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/application_note/gpio/wiringpi) for Odroid specific information.

Hope it helps.